# How do I install nvidia driver version 375?

Tags: debian, apt, nvidia

I have a GTX 1050 TI which requires the driver version 375.
my sources.list looks like :

```
# deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian experimental main contrib non-free
```

I have run sudo apt-get update.

When im doing sudo apt-get -t experimental install nvidia-driver 
im getting the error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-driver : Depends: nvidia-driver-libs (= 375.20-2) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: nvidia-driver-bin (= 375.20-2) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia (= 375.20-2) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: nvidia-vdpau-driver (= 375.20-2) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: nvidia-alternative (= 375.20-2) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: nvidia-kernel-dkms (= 375.20-2) but it is not going to be installed or
                          nvidia-kernel-375.20
                 Recommends: nvidia-settings (>= 375) but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: nvidia-persistenced but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo 'deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ experimental main contrib non-free' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/experimental.list
apt-get source nvidia-driver=375.20-2
apt-get build-dep nvidia-driver
cd nvidia-graphics-drivers-375.20/
dpkg-buildpackage
cd ..
dpkg -i nvidia*.deb
```

Comment: this doesnt install nvidia-smi. :/

Comment: Why?
`ls -la nvidia-smi_375.20-2_i386.deb 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 335136 Nov 30 01:40 nvidia-smi_375.20-2_i386.deb`

Comment: @harvey_slash you need to remove the `experimental` repo , just keep the source.

Comment: @IporSircer, I am trying to follow your instruction to install nvidia-driver=375.66-1~bpo8+1 from jessie-backports (because if I try to install it using `sudo apt-get install -t jessie-backports nvidia-driver` it installs 340) BUT I get the following error: `E: Build-Depends dependency for nvidia-graphics-drivers cannot be satisfied because candidate version of package debhelper can't satisfy version requirements` when executing `sudo apt-get build-dep nvidia-driver`. Could you please give a hint how I can fix this?

Comment: @Ingvord: i haven't write any `apt-get install` line.

Comment: @IporSircer yes you are right - you did not. I mean when I try to install drivers version=375 via `apt-get install -t jessie-backports` apt-get does not do this, but instead installs 340. So I tried your recipe but bumped into `dependency for nvidia-graphics-drivers cannot be satisfied` problem

Comment: I have finally managed to install nvidia-driver=375 from jessie-backports. I had to purge currently installed version `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*`; reboot (this is important!!!); install via `sudo apt-get install -t jessie-backports nvidia-driver`